# .gitignore everything but .c and .h recursively

Tags: c, git, gitignore

I would like to ignore everything in a certain folder and its subfolders, except for `.c` and `.h` files.

Yet locally, i need other files too. Do i have to have these files, which should not be tracked, in the git-repo before or after i add the `.gitignore`?

And how do i do this?:

```
#ignore all
*
#but:
!source/**/*.c
!source/**/*.h
```

This is my current solution, but it does not work. But i think this also relates to the point in time, where i have to add the files, that should be ignored, but need to be there locally?

EDIT:
The problem is, i got a copy of a project, that does all kinds of makefile magic and other things, i do not even know what kind of file-types and subfolders there are (i will only work in one folder of the massive project, so i don't think, that the gitignore needs to be so exclusive) ... and i can't just commit everything, because the "lib" has to be installed i think, so everybody needs to do this on his own ...

Comment: I’ve said this elsewhere, but I prefer to ignore more specific patterns; also, you can bypass gitignore when you git add with -f.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring `*` means ignore everything including top-level directories. After that `git` doesn't even look into subdirectories. To fix that unignore directories. Your entire `.gitignore` should look like this:

```
# Ignore all
*

# Unignore directories
!*/

# Unignore source code files
!source/**/*.c
!source/**/*.h
```

Another approach is to ignore everything but force-add necessary files with [`git add -f`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--f).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the pattern

> ```
> *
> ```

excludes all directories, too.  According to [the `gitignore` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore),

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.

To make this work, then, you'll need to use make sure that directories are not ignored. <s>The gitignore pattern format does not provide a way to distinguish between directories and regular files, so you'll need to do that manually.</s>  One possibility would be to put a `.gitignore` file in each that directory that reincludes all its subdirectories, but it would be easier to just reinclude all directories.  These can be matched (exclusively) with a pattern that ends with a '/':

```
!source/**/
```

Also, you are right when you say

> But i think this also relates to the point in time, where i have to add the files, that should be ignored

in the sense that gitignore does not apply to files that are already tracked.

Comment: So what is best way to proceed? I would like to have this folder in the repo, which contains c files, but also other files like makefiles, etc. These will change overtime, but should not be tracked, while the c files and the h files will be changed and should be tracked

Comment: As I said, @CleboSevic, each directory can have its own `.gitignore` file that re-includes that directory's subdirectories (by explicit name).  Or there are other ways that you could re-include the directories.  But, honestly, I would recommend *not* taking your approach in the first place.  Write patterns that ignore the specific files you want to ignore, not all files by default.

Comment: The problem is, i got a copy of a project, that does all kinds of makefile magic and other things, i do not even know what kind of file-types and subfolders there are (i will only work in one folder of the massive project, so i don't think, that the gitignore needs to be so exclusive) ... and i can't just commit everything, because the "lib" has to be installed i think, so everybody needs to do this on his own ...

Comment: "*The gitignore pattern format does not provide a way to distinguish between directories and regular files*" That's not exactly true. To distinguish directories add a slash at the end of the format. To unignore directories use pattern `!*/`